# Pdfjs viewer with external file upload

Tags: html, ajax, pdf, dropzone.js, pdf.js

I am loading the pdf.js viewer in my webpage in a div using the pdf.js API methods such as run and open.

In this page I also have a file upload section to attach related documents.

The issue is when I upload a document in the file upload section, using dropzone, the pdf viewer thinks I am uploading a document to it and changes the existing document. Is there a setting to turn this off? I thought there would be something in network.js but I haven't found anything promising yet.

Comment: Are you using a customized version of the project's [viewer](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) example, or the display layer API directly with `PDFJS.getDocument` and manual rendering onto canvas elements like [this](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/)? Or a third-party wrapper?

Comment: Im using the API directly. I give the PDFViewerApplication my config, which tells it the layout elements and then I call open with my URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the offending part in PDFViewerApplication](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/a9a3396f3d7121a66081279a92cb1fbbd7b20b07/web/app.js#L1841), it adds a global `change` event listener and changes the pdf if it's a file input with files selected.

Unfortunately there is no settings flag to disable this behaviour, no reference to the listener function to remove it, and also no way to cancel or change the event (it would also break other parts of the app), so you'll have to modify this code to remove it. Seems like the listener just dispatches a new internal `fileinputchange` event which is only used for this, so you only need to comment out [this line](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/a9a3396f3d7121a66081279a92cb1fbbd7b20b07/web/app.js#L1311).

Comment: That did it! I have been digging around for 2 days now and never saw that. Thank you so much! Just curious, do you know how to have multiple pdfjs viewers in the same page without using iFrames?

Comment: I have a single page app and a viewer in two different sections and I haven't found a nice way to clean them up. I have tried removing their dom but haven't had any success and couldn't find a destroy method in the app.js file

Comment: Yeah I saw your question earlier regarding that. Tbh this viewer is really just intented as a demo/example implementation, and looking at the code it's pretty unsuitable for that kind of contained existence, its a single instance object with direct hooks to everything in the window. You could ditch it and just use the display layer with PDJS.getDocument, render the pages onto canvases like in the example and add the few UI functions you really need (like zooming, jumping to pages), it can be done in a few hundred lines of code.

Comment: I got this working by removing the dom when i leave the page, removing the overlay models and making the viewer config look for things by class instead of ids. Thanks for all your help