# Add Javascript calls to the text layer (div) over a pdf.js viewer (canvas)

Tags: javascript, promise, pdf.js

I want to superimpose interactivity over text elements of a PDF rendered by [`pdf.js`](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js).

The approach I'm thinking is to add Javascript calls to the `<spans>` rendered in the text layer `<div>` that `pdf.js` adds over the `<canvas>` to enable text highlighting and selecting.

I am starting from the [`gh-pages.zip`](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Setup-PDF.js-in-a-website#examples) template, adding code to the [app.js PDFViewerApplication.run() method](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/web/app.js#L477) like so:

```
run(config) {
  this.initialize(config).then(function() {
    webViewerInitialized();
    console.log(PDFViewerApplication);
    PDFViewerApplication.pdfDocument.getPage(1);
    PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.viewer.children[1].outerHTML =
      '...<span  style="left: 72px; top: 98.5212px; font-size: 11.9552px; font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(0.895184);"  onclick="console.log(\'Hence, recording and compiling a trace\')">Hence, recording and compiling a trace</span>...';
  });
},
```

`pdfDocument` is `null`, so the `getPage` line returns:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPage' of null at eval (app.js:481)

`children[1]` is `undefined`, including if I scroll to the right page then refresh (pdf.js automatically scrolls to the same place that was last displayed).

I assume `pdfDocument` and `children` might be populated asynchronously but I don't know how to wait, and I assume there's a better way to edit the text layer `<spans>`?

Comment: Run a test to see what `PDFViewerApplication.pdfDocument.getPage(1)` returns. It might be a Promise, in which case it needs to be returned, and `PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.....()` executed in a further `then()`.

Comment: Thanks very much @Roamer-1888, unfortunately `pdfDocument` is `null`, so I just get `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPage' of null at eval (app.js:481)`. I've improved my question, thanks.

Comment: Maybe there's something async in `this.initialize()` that is not acknowledged in its returned Promise.

Comment: Thanks @Roamer-1888, `webViewerInitialized ` includes calls to async functions, but `await`ing them (and making the inline function `async`) doesn't ensure subsequent calls come after `pdfDocument` is loaded. Maybe I need to add an event listener for a custom event, but no examples of `pdf.js` deployment seem to mention one.

Comment: Chris, if you add the code for `initialize()` and `webViewerInitialized()` to the question, I'll see if I can spot something.

Comment: Thanks very much @Roamer-1888, here's [initialize](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/web/app.js#L188), and here's [webViewerInitialized](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/web/app.js#L1798). I am currently exploring using the [custom events](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/f83bd721fc0fbc382f0059903e1f16a410401732/web/dom_events.js#L20) the library throws, as suggested [here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/9527). Although a sensible comment under [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39841788/1308967) suggests I should rewrite the viewer. Wary though.

Comment: I am wary because there seems to have been a lot of cross-browser testing that I'd lose if I rewrite, and my project needs to run on all browsers on old, cheap phones.

Comment: After a quick look at `initialize()`, i'd have to say it's not particularly well written. The last few lines of the function are rather confusing. It dispatches a 'localized' event on the `eventBus` once the viewer has been fully initialized and translated and it's possible that you are supposed to attach an event hander (how?) rather than chain `.then()`. The way `initialised()` is written, the two are not the same as each other. A "fix"  would be quite simple but may not be the right thing to do.

Comment: You are exactly right, thank you! With help from a pdf.js developer, I am starting to understand the (very hard to use and very recently changed) event bus, using an approach I document [on github](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/9527#issuecomment-604188423), and possibly running into bugs with it which I arrogantly propose a PR for. I think the complexity is they're using the same multi-threaded code for being built into Firefox, for being a npm/bower package, being a compiled distro, being a Chrome extension and being a Firefox extension.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the author made `.initialize()` `async` just so he could use `await`, without paying attention to the need for the returned Promise to settle after *all* the internally called asynchronous processes have settled. Awaiting `this.l10n.translate(appContainer).then(...);` will allow you to (more) reliably chain `.then()` where you call the function, but will also have the side effect of pushing `this._initializedCapability.resolve()` into a nextTick thread. Shouldn't matter but who knows, I'm only guessing.

Comment: I am assuming the architecture is good and trying to learn from it, as it is written by Firefox who should know about Javascript architecture, so I'm interested if you're seeing otherwise and I need to show less respect! Is it possible they have deliberately left some asynchronous processes running so that others that don't depend on them can be kicked off before they finish? (Not tagging you as this isn't urgent enough to interrupt you.)

Comment: Caller of an `async` function has a right to expect the returned Promise to settle in response to *all* async activity initiated by the called function. I rather imaging that `.initialize()` has grown over time and has been worked on by a number of individuals. Try adding `await` as I suggest above and stick with your existing `this.initialize(config).then(...)`. This is much simpler than subscribing to an event with the added advantage that you can (and should) also chain `.catch(...)`.

Comment: @Chris has the situation improved for this or you've moved on?

Comment: @aehlke I've posted what I can find from my repo, but it is just an approximate possible set of ideas that may or may not help, tbh.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas for solving this issue, but they will need some work as I'm quoting code I haven't touched in 4 years. Not marking as an answer as it is just a few slightly random initial pointers.

I started off by adding event listeners to viewer.js. Here's the function:

```
function attachEventListeners(viewerApp) {
    console.log("attachEventListeners called");
    document.addEventListener("documentload", function() {
        console.log("documentload fired");
    });
    document.addEventListener("pagerendered", function() {
        console.log("pagerendered fired");
    });
    document.addEventListener("textlayerrendered", function() {
        console.log("textlayerrendered fired");
    });
    document.addEventListener("pagechange", function() {
        console.log("pagechange fired");
    });
    document.addEventListener("pagesinit", function() {
        console.log("pagesinit fired");
    });
    document.addEventListener("pagesloaded", function() {
        console.log("pagesloaded fired");
    });
    document.addEventListener("scalechange", function() {
        console.log("scalechange fired");
    });
    document.addEventListener("updateviewarea", function() {
        console.log("updateviewarea fired");
    });
    document.addEventListener("find", function() {
        console.log("find fired");
    });
    document.addEventListener("attachmentsloaded", function() {
        console.log("attachmentsloaded fired");
    });
    document.addEventListener("sidebarviewchanged", function() {
        console.log("sidebarviewchanged fired");
    });
    document.addEventListener("pagemode", function() {
        console.log("pagemode fired");
    });
    document.addEventListener("namedaction", function() {
        console.log("namedaction fired");
    });
    document.addEventListener("presentationmodechanged", function() {
        console.log("presentationmodechanged fired");
    });
    document.addEventListener("outlineloaded", function() {
        console.log("outlineloaded fired");
    });
}
```

Then called this in the `function webViewerLoad()` with (twice, in each `if` clause):

```
window.PDFViewerApplicationOptions.set("disablePreferences", true);
window.PDFViewerApplicationOptions.set("eventBusDispatchToDOM", true);
attachEventListeners(window.PDFViewerApplication);
```

In my case I needed the textlayerrendered event:

```
viewerApp.eventBus.on("textlayerrendered", function(evt) {
    console.log("textlayerrendered fired", evt);
    for (const span of evt.source.textDivs) {
    span.onclick = function() {
        console.log(this.innerHTML);
    };
    const el = document.createElement("img");
    el.src = "images/study.png";
    el.style.position = "absolute";
    el.style.top = `${span.offsetTop}px`;
    el.style.left = `${span.offsetLeft + span.offsetWidth + 10}px`;
    // el.style.width = "10px";
    el.style.height = `${span.offsetHeight}px`;
    el.style.zIndex = 10;
    // el.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
    el.style.fontSize = span.style.fontSize;
    el.style.fontFamily = span.style.fontFamily;
    el.style.transform = span.style.transform;
    el.style.opacity = 0.4;
    span.parentNode.insertBefore(el, span.nextSibling);
    span.onmouseover = function() {
        el.style.opacity = 1;
        el.style.zIndex = 11;
    };
    span.onmouseout = function() {
        el.style.opacity = 0.4;
        el.style.zIndex = 10;
    };
    }
});
```

So the first part of the `webViewerLoad()` function became:

```
function webViewerLoad() {
    const config = getViewerConfiguration();
    if (typeof PDFJSDev === "undefined" || !PDFJSDev.test("PRODUCTION")) {
    Promise.all([
        SystemJS.import("pdfjs-web/app.js"),
        SystemJS.import("pdfjs-web/app_options.js"),
        SystemJS.import("pdfjs-web/genericcom.js"),
        SystemJS.import("pdfjs-web/pdf_print_service.js"),
    ]).then(function([app, appOptions, ...otherModules]) {
        window.PDFViewerApplication = app.PDFViewerApplication;
        window.PDFViewerApplicationOptions = appOptions.AppOptions;
        window.PDFViewerApplication.initializedPromise.then(function() {
        console.log("initializedPromise.then called");
        attachEventListeners(window.PDFViewerApplication);
        window.PDFViewerApplication.eventBus.on("documenloaded", function(
            event
        ) {
            console.log("The document has now been loaded", event);
            attachEventListeners(window.PDFViewerApplication);
        });
        });
        app.PDFViewerApplication.run(config);
    });
    } else {
```

I was working from commit 3cebb430c2ae3ebc6af110648c2577374c74c11c in the pdf.js library should this help.

Apologies this is probably outdated but gives a few pointers. Here is a working page https://ethiopialearning.com/content/page?id=46240 , but the Javascript is all compiled so probably not much use. Also, I found pdf.js very slow for some of my really nastily tangled PDFs, so I had to render an image then super-impose just the invisible interaction layer of pdf.js.